# Manifesto Preparation by Political parties in India

Tags: parties, india, campaigning

I was browsing through the manifesto of INC for the parliamentary election, 2019. There were some really good ideas in all areas. The promises and plan of action were spread across all types of topics from defence, education, social justice etc. My question is how do they prepare the manifesto? Do they have a research wing? Are there public consultations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, infact all parties have a research wing & manifesto committees, who conduct the research & prepare the manifesto.
In this case Dr. P Chidambaram was the manifesto committee chairman & the Congress also acknowledged that they held 121 public & 53 closed door consultations